# Add custom buttons in Angular Highcharts Line Chart

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I'm trying to add 2 custom buttons in Angular Highcharts Line chart in the exporting property

```
exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    buttons: {
        customButton: {
            text: 'Custom Button',
            click: () => {
                alert('You pressed the button!');
            },
        },
        anotherButton: {
            text: 'Another Button',
            click: () => {
                alert('You pressed another button!');
            },
        },
    },
}
```

But these 2 buttons not displaying. What could be the missing logic here?
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9nkrgd-iwgbma?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **exporting.buttons** is an option to edit the buttons in the exporting menu only: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons

To render the custom buttons use the **SVGRenderer** feature: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#button

You can add those buttons in the **render** callback - calls after initial load and after each redraw: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: Is there any example of this with Typescript?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-wp43k here is an example with using Angular. You should be able to customize it easily to your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Hi think the below snippet will help you:

```
chart: {
  type: "line",
  renderTo: "chart",
  events: {
    render(events) {
      let chart = this;

      if (chart.customButton) {
        chart.customButton.destroy();
      }
      chart.customButton = chart.renderer
        .button("custom button", 100, 40, () => {
          console.log("clicked.....");
          chart.exportChart({
            type: "application/pdf",
            filename: "line-chart"
          });
        })
        .add();
    }
  }
}
```

Here on click the button, you can implement the export. The example here exports PDF.

Demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-functionality?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstackoverflow%2Fhigh-chart-question%2Fhigh-chart-question.component.ts

https://highcharts-angular-functionality.stackblitz.io/exportcolor

Hope this helps.